# How to solve a Quasi-Linear PDE

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of,

$u_xx(z-2y^2)=(z-u_yy)(z-y^2-2x^3)$

Attempt:

1) Set up the symmetric system,

$\frac{dx}{x(z-2y^2)}=\frac{dy}{y(z-y^2-2x^3)}=\frac{dz}{0}=\frac{du}{z(z-y^2-2x^3)}$

2) Solve the system of ODE's

$\frac{dz}{0}$ implies $z=C_1$

$\frac{y^{-1}dy-z^{-1}du}{0}=\frac{d(\log y-z^{-1}u)}{0}$ implies $\log y-\frac{u}{z}=C_2$

3) The third one is really tuff and I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: looks like separation of variables and casting $u(x,y,z)$ as $u(x,y,z) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$ type thing?

Comment: That would only give solutions of the form $XYZ$, I'm looking for the general solution but thanks!

Comment: @user423573 :  Your system of ODEs is correct. I agree with the two characteristic equations that you found. Unfortunately the third seems arduous. It can be slightly simplified with the change of variables $X=x^3$ and $Y=y^2$. This leads to an Abel's differential equation of the second kind. There is no general method to solve this kind of equations. They are solvable only in particular cases. So, may be possible, but with little hope. Good luck !